# PhoneGap SplashScreen doesn't work

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

today I hava a lot of trouble with Splashscreens for different resolutions.

My splash part in config.xml:

```
<gap:splash src="Splash_1536x2048_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />
<gap:splash src="Splash_2048x1536_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />

<gap:splash src="Splash_320x480_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="Splash_480x320_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="480" height="320" />

<gap:splash src="Splash_640x960_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="Splash_960x640_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="960" height="640" />

<gap:splash src="Splash_640x1136_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
<gap:splash src="Splash_1136x640_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1136" height="640" />

<gap:splash src="Splash_750x1334_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
<gap:splash src="Splash_1334x1334_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1334" height="750" />

<gap:splash src="Splash_1242x2208_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208" />
<gap:splash src="Splash_2208x1242_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242" />
```

These png files are stored at root, /splash AND res/screen/ios but even if i change the path in XML to some of the possible files locations the image doesn't load on app start.

If I use:

```
<!--iPhone and iPod touch-->
<gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />

<!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
<!--<gap:splash src="Default-568h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />-->
<gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />

<!-- iPhone 6 -->
<!--<gap:splash src="Default-667h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />-->
<gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
<!--<gap:splash src="Default-Portrait-736h@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208" />-->
<gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208" />
<!--<gap:splash src="Default-Landscape-736h@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242" />-->
<gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242" />

<!--iPad -->
<gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
<gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />

<!--Retina iPad -->
<gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />
<gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />
```

the default splash are displayed. But I want to use the different images for different resolutions...

Please help me :-)

Comment: Have you used Preference tag? And which plugin, exactly, are you using?

Comment: Preference Tag:
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="false" />

<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />

<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" /> 

Plug-In:
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" source="npm" />

Comment: Are you using PhoneGap Build?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the follwing link. Might be it helps.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't help me...I use this Plugin correctly.

Comment: Is there something to know about the naming because with splash.png it works and with Splash_320x200_Leopold_City.png it doesn't

Comment: Yes Sven. It only took the name as splash. Please use the image name as splash.png.

Comment: but how i can handle different resolutions if i use just splash.png as image name?

Comment: Save a splash.png, splash.psd or splash.ai file within the resources directory at the root of the Cordova project. Splash screen dimensions vary for each platform, device and orientation, so a square source image is required the generate each of various sizes. The source image’s minimum dimensions should be 2208x2208 px, and its artwork should be centered within the square, knowing that each generated image will be center cropped into landscape and portrait images. The splash screen’s artwork should roughly fit within a center square (1200x1200 px).

Comment: Put your splash.png in resource folder, where you placed your icon. After that use command cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen. Hope it works.

Comment: ok, so it is not possible to use different images for vary platform, device and orientation? Tanks

Comment: It automatically creates images for diffrent sizes and put into resources/android/splash directory.

Comment: I want to define different images, are there any possibility?

Answer (score 0):

If you build the app using Phonegap Build, there should be a splash.png in your root folder. Try to add platform specific splash screens as below. File name and path you can change.

```
   <gap:splash src="splash.png" />

    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"    gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"          gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png"       gap:platform="ios"     width="1536" height="2048" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"  />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="2048" height="1536" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape.png"    gap:platform="ios"     width="480" height="320" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="960" height="640" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-667h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait-736h@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242" />
```

Comment: This is like phonegap documentation, but doesn't work in my case...Above I added the current version of my config.xml

Answer (score 0):

This is the current version of my config.xml. This doesn't work...

```
<gap:splash src="splash.png" />
```

```
<gap:splash src="Splash_1536x2048_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />
<gap:splash src="Splash_2048x1536_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />

<gap:splash src="Splash_320x480_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="Splash_480x320_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="480" height="320" />

<gap:splash src="Splash_640x960_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="Splash_960x640_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="960" height="640" />

<gap:splash src="Splash_640x1136_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
<gap:splash src="Splash_1136x640_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1136" height="640" />

<gap:splash src="Splash_750x1334_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
<gap:splash src="Splash_1334x1334_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1334" height="750" />

<gap:splash src="Splash_1242x2208_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208" />
<gap:splash src="Splash_2208x1242_Leopold_City.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242" />
```